# Class 'auth' not found in some views

Tags: php, laravel

i put this code to my header layout that get a field from users table

```
<li class="tophe">
Your ID is :   {{auth::user()->shenase}}
</li>
```

This code works good to my index page but when i open other pages i get this error

```
Class 'auth' not found (View: 
###\resources\views\layouts\panel\header.blade.php)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel, there is an auth helper you can use to get the information you need about the currently authenticated user and you use it like so :

```
<li class="tophe">
Your ID is :   {{auth()->user()->someAttribute}}
</li>
// not auth alone it's a function
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use it as `Auth`, or `auth()`:

```php
<li class="tophe">
Your ID is :   {{auth()->user()->shenase}}
</li>
```

Or:

```php
<li class="tophe">
Your ID is :   {{Auth::user()->shenase}}
</li>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="tophe">
Your ID is : {{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->shenase}}
</li>
```

You can try with give absolute path to auth class

Comment: Please modify your answer with the actual requirememnt.